# Springboot ReqeustBody input Validation for HTML elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, request

I am looking for a way to validate Request body fields for HTML content in my Springboot application as below

```
{
    "name": "<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>",
    "value": "<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>"
}
```

I am aware that I can make use of @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]*", message = "Name can only have letters") from javax.validation. (There are different use cases where I may need to add different complex regex to satisfy many request body fields).
Is there any other way to block HTML elements in Springboot?